# vba regex: dot matching newline

Tags: regex, vba

I want to match (in this snippet) everything upto but not including a newline which is what I thought a . would do. Could someone shed light on what I'm missing please.

```
Public Sub regexp()

Dim oRegExp As regexp
Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
Dim oMatch As Match
Dim sString As String

sString = _
    "one" & vbNewLine & _
    "two" & vbNewLine

Set oRegExp = New regexp
With oRegExp
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = ".+"
    Set oMatches = .Execute(sString)
    For Each oMatch In oMatches
        Debug.Print "*" & oMatch.Value & "*"
    Next oMatch
End With

End Sub
```

Output is

```
*one
*
*two
*
```

Expected output

```
*one*
*two*
```

How can I avoid the newline in the output? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `[^\n]` in place of `.`, it will match any character *except* the new line character.

Comment: Sadly, that gives me the same output.

Comment: Try `[^\n\r]` instead - The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbnewline.aspx) suggests that `vbNewLine` is only a new line character, but I have some vague recollection it's actually the system-specific new line character sequence, which includes a carriage return on Windows.

Comment: That was it, thanks very much. The real case was a text file and your solution works fine on that too. Again, thanks.