# Excluding line breaks from regex capture

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I realise that a similar question has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297365/vba-regex-dot-matching-newline) and answered, but the problem persists after I've tried the solution proposed in that answer.

I want to write an Excel macro to separate a multi-line string into multiple single lines, trimmed of whitespace including line breaks. This is my code:

```
Sub testRegexMatch()
    Dim r As New VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp
    Dim str As String
    Dim mc As MatchCollection
    r.Pattern = "[\r\n\s]*([^\r\n]+?)[\s\r\n]*$"
    r.Global = True
    r.MultiLine = True
    str = "This is a haiku" & vbCrLf _
        & "You may read it if you wish   " & vbCrLf _
        & "   but you don't have to"
    Set mc = r.Execute(str)
    For Each Line In mc
      Debug.Print "^" & Line & "$"
    Next Line
End Sub
```

Expected output:

```
^This is a haiku$
^You may read it if you wish$
^but you don't have to$
```

Actual output:

```
^This is a haiku
$
^
You may read it if you wish   
$
^
   but you don't have to$
```

I've tried the same thing on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sJ2sN3/1), but this appears to show the correct captures, so it must be a quirk of VBA's regex engine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, *captures* (=`SubMatches`) is the word here. You are grabbing the matches themselves. Access the `.SubMatches(0)` substrings.

Comment: when you are using `\s`, what is the need of `\n` and `\r`??Is `\s` treated differently in vba?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that does the trick - post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @rock321987: good point, I added the \n\r because I'd been trying variations on it in an effort to get it to work and had forgotten to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to access the captured values via [`SubMatches()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y27d2s18(v=vs.84).aspx):

> When a regular expression is executed, zero or more submatches can result when ***subexpressions are enclosed in capturing parentheses***. Each item in the `SubMatches` collection is the string found and captured by the regular expression.

Here is my demo:

```
Sub DemoFn()
   Dim re, targetString, colMatch, objMatch
   Set re = New regexp
   With re
     .pattern = "\s*([^\r\n]+?)\s*$"
     .Global = True              ' Same as /g at the online tester
     .MultiLine = True           ' Same as /m at regex101.com
   End With
   targetString = "This is a haiku  " & vbLf & "  You may read it if you wish " & vbLf & "    but you don't have to"
   Set colMatch = re.Execute(targetString)
   For Each objMatch In colMatch
     Debug.Print objMatch.SubMatches.Item(0) ' <== SEE HERE
   Next
End Sub
```

It prints:

```
This is a haiku
You may read it if you wish
but you don't have to
```

Comment: Updated to remove unnecessary character classes related to whitespace matching.